# Failed to convert structure to matrix with regionprops in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I am working with particle tracking in images in MATLAB and using [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#input_argument_output) function. On the provided resource there is an example with circles:

```
stats = regionprops('table',bw,'Centroid',...
'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength')  
centers = stats.Centroid;
diameters = mean([stats.MajorAxisLength stats.MinorAxisLength],2);
radii = diameters/2;
```

In my Matlab R2014b, the line `centers = stats.Centroid;` produces undesired result: my `stats.Centroid` structure has 20 elements (each element is two numbers - the coordinates of the center of the region). However, after the following command, my variable `center` is only `1x2` matrix, instead of desired `20x2`.

Screenshot attached.

[image]

I tried to go around this with different methods. The only solution I found is to do:

```
t=zeros(20,2);
for i=1:20
    t(i,:)=stats(i).Centroid;
end
```

However, as we all know loops are slow in MATLAB. Is there another method that takes advantage of MATLAB matrix operations?

Comment: I don't have matlab available to check right now, but does stats(1:end).Centroid give you a 20x2 matrix?

Comment: No, result is the same! I tryied  that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `stats.Centroid` would in fact give you a [**comma-separated list**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of centroids, so MATLAB would only give you the first centre of that matrix if you did `centers = stats.Centroid`.  What you must do is encapsulate the centres in an array (i.e. `[stats.Centroid]`), then **reshape** when you're done.

Something like this should work for you:

```
centers = reshape([stats.Centroid], 2, []).';
```

What this will do is read in the centroids as a `1 x 2*M` array where `M` is the total number of blobs and because MATLAB does reshaping in column-major format, you should make sure that specify the total number of rows to be 2 and let MATLAB figure out how many columns there are after by itself.  You would then transpose the result when you're done to complete what you want.

## Minor Note

If you look at the `regionprops` documentation page in their Tips section - http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#buorh6l-1, you will see that they surround `stats.Area`, which is the area of each blob with `[]` brackets to ensure that the comma-separated list of values is encapsulated in an array.  This is not an accident and there is a purpose of having those there and I've basically told you what that was.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this works! I think, the latest version implicitly converts comma separated list into array

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. I don't own the newest version... But this is what I've always done anyhow :)